# Problem in obtaining output, if statement maybe?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    int rev_num=0,x=0,n,a;
    printf("Enter a number");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=n+1;i<i+1;i++)
    {   
        a=i;
        while(a>0)
        {
            rev_num=rev_num*10+a%10;
            a/=10;
        }
        for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
        {   
            x=0;
            if(i%j==0)
            {
                x=1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(x==0 && i==rev_num)
        {
            printf("%d is the next prime palindrome",i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

We have to find next prime palindrome of a number, but the code is not giving any o/p, nor any error. It just keeps asking for input indefintely.Why????

Comment: `i<i+1` is a recipe for infinite loop (until overflow).

Comment: `for(int i=n+1;i<i+1;i++)` signed integer overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: I think you need `rev_num=0` inside the `for` loop. Otherwise it is only initialised once.

Comment: What the other commenters are getting at is that you've defined your loop stopping condition as `i<i+1`, which means that your stop condition is always one more than the current value of `i`. Since `i` increments by 1 every loop iteration, you end up with an infinite loop until `i` overflows.

Comment: `i<i+1` is not a problem here, since the loop is supposed to run until it reaches the `break`. The actual problem may be what Weather Vane pointed out regarding `rev_num`.

Comment: @WeatherVane got it right the second time.  The loop is infinite but clearly on purpose (the more idiomatic way to write it is `for(int i=n+1; ;i++)`. The problem is that `rev_num` is not reset, so what's supposed to be the reverse (e.g. 1234 -> 4321) instead has a garbage value, so `i==rev_num` doesn't match expected palindromes and fails to `break;` the loop

Comment: **WeatherVane** thanks a lot, i just did what u said and its working now. Thanks again for help!!!!!!